# Where is workflow task info stored?

Tags: workflow, rules-engine

I have looked through dozens of table information and schema info but I can't find the "Workflow Task Detail" table and the connections to the "Rules Using This Task".

I'm trying to add a trigger which will modify a date based on the "Unique Name" naming convention my client uses.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you would be looking for is the ActionTask object (key prefix 01V). Unfortunately, you cannot query this table, because it is not exposed in any API, nor can you directly modify these items, because it requires the metadata API. As a workaround, you could use a formula field to determine which date to set. Unfortunately, this is the best that you can do under the current situation with the API.

Comment: Thank you. We ended up moving the key word from the Unique Name into the Comments since the Comments are carried over to the task itself and exposed in apex.

Comment: @Aba Great. I'm glad I could help point you in the right direction.